# Changing order with CheckBox

Tags: javafx

i am working on an application in which if user select the CheckBox the Order of rectangle is changed, like Blue Rectangle comes first and red second.

Here is example code. I tried with "setOnAcation" it didn't work obviously i am duplicating child!! do i have to add listener to box? Please..

Thank you

```
public class Main extends Application{ 
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            // Displaying all the functions in Scene
            StackPane border = new StackPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(border, 750, 500);
            primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            HBox h1 = new HBox(20);
            h1.setPadding(new Insets(20));
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox("Switch Places");
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(200,200);
            rect1.setFill(null);
            rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);

            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200,200);
            rect2.setFill(null);
            rect2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

            h1.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,box);

            box.setOnAction((e)->{
                if (box.isSelected()){
                    h1.getChildren().addAll(rect2,rect1,box);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Checkbox1 is not selected");
                }

            });

            border.getChildren().add(h1);

        }

        /**
         * @param args
         *            the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove duplicate child in h1 using clear() method after add a new child as:

```
box.setOnAction((e) -> {
        if (box.isSelected()) {
            h1.getChildren().clear();
            h1.getChildren().addAll(rect2, rect1, box);
        } 
 });
```

Comment: Wow.Thank you so much Keyur

Comment: Thank you so much but if i may ask another question related to this, if i have second CheckBox and on that box i want Rectangles to be upside down (Like in VBox) how do i do that?

Comment: VBox p = new VBox();                                                    box1.setOnAction((e)->{
         if(box1.isSelected()){
          p.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,box,box1);
         }
        });                                                                                                              i Tried with this but everything disappears.

Comment: VBox p = new VBox();
  box1.setOnAction((e) -> {
   if (box1.isSelected()) {
    p.getChildren().clear();
    p.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2, box, box1);
    border.getChildren().clear();
    border.getChildren().add(p);
   }
  });